# CQWP Multiple Value People Field Filter

Tags: content-query-web-part

I'm on SP2013. I have a content type called Projects with a multi-valued People field called Project Members and two single-valued People field called Project Lead and Client Sponsor. I'm trying to configure a CQWP on the main portal page to pull in Project content types from the whole site collection and filter on:

Project Members = [Me]
or Project Lead = [Me]
or Client Sponsor = [Me]

The problem is when I select "Show items from all sites in this site collection" in the configuration of the web part, the Project Members column does not show up. However, if I select "Show items from the following list" and point it a specific Project list, the Project Members column shows up.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. If anyone is curious, here's what I did:

1. Export your CQWP. Open in SPD.
2. Search for the CommonViewFields tag and put in your column name there.
3. Search for the AdditionalFilterFields tag and put in your column there.'
4. Save the web part and import it to your page.
5. The new field should appear in the filter list.